# Deserializing PMD output with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, pmd

I'm trying to deserialize the output of PMD using Jackson. Specifically, I want to obtain a list of violations and their data, which PMD gives me in the following form:

```
<pmd-cpd>
<duplication lines="615" tokens="1188">
<file line="126" path="Some\Path\Here"/>
<file line="126" path="Some\Path\Here"/>
<codefragment>
<![CDATA[
SomeCodeFragmentHere
]]>
</codefragment>
</duplication>
MoreDuplications
</pmd-cpd>
```

I currently have the following classes to deserialize into:

```
public class PmdResults {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "duplication")
  List<CodeClone> codeClones;
}

public class CodeClone {
  public int lines;
  public int tokens;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "file")
  public List<SourceFile> files;

  public CodeClone() { super(); }
  
  public static class SourceFile {
    public int line;
    public String path;
  }
}
```

Currently, Jackson is able to deserialize the root and both "lines" and "tokens" correctly. However, rather than attempting to deserialize the two "file" elements into SourceFile objects, it looks directly for a "line" attribute to deserialize the attributes of those elements. I'm also not sure how to have Jackson ignore the "codefragment" element, given that I do not actually need that information. I'd be very grateful for any help in this regard, as I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding why it was able to identify that the duplication elements should become objects in a list, but not the file elements which seem to follow the same format.

PS.: I would actually prefer to get rid of the PmdResults class altogether, and directly deserialize a List<CodeClone>, but I've been unable to find any way to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of problems in your Java code:

---

In your Java code you have properties of type `List<...>`

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "duplication")
List<CodeClone> codeClones;
```

and

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "file")
List<SourceFiles> files;
```

You need do annotate these `List` properties
also with `@JacksonXmlWrapper(useWrapping = false)`.
If you omit this, then the default would be `useWrapping = true`
and Jackson would expect for example

```
<file>  
  <file>...</file>
  <file>...</file>
</file>
```

instead of just

```
<file>...</file>
<file>...</file>
```

See also the [Java doc of `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html).

---

In your XML example you have several XML attributes
(like  `line="126"`or `path="Some\Path\Here"`)
which are of course different from
XML elements (like `<line>126</line>` or
`<path>Some\Path\Here</path>`).

You need to tell Jackson these are XML attributes by annotating
the Java property with `@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)`.
If you omit this, then the default is `isAttribute = false`
and Jackson would expect an XML element instead of an XML attribute.

See also the [Java doc of `@JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html).